# setInterval is making the app freeze after a while

Tags: javascript, ajax, socket.io, setinterval

I've set up a setInterval function which runs after 5 seconds. It basically gets data from the database and updates the store. It works really well for like 5 minutes and then it makes the tab really slow.

```
setInterval(
  function() {
    socket.emit("read sync", UserStore.obj.user_id);

    socket.on("sync success", function(data) {
      UserStore.obj.rooms = data[0].rooms;
    });
  }.bind(this),
  5000
);
```

The app really freezes up and hangs. is there a simpler alternative to this?

Comment: Move the `socket.on("sync success")` out of the `setInterval` other than that, run a profiler over your JS, it might not be this that is causing the issue.

Comment: Are you sure is realy setInterval that is the problem or the programme have consume your system memory and making it slow.

Comment: This is clearly a memory consumption issue. Does it happen on all browsers?

Comment: It probably is a memory consumption issue. It keeps retrieving data from database every 5 seconds. How do I resolve this?